# Utf8 characters cut off when saving text field in mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, utf-8

I'm working on a website in which we save Japanese characters in a text field.

The table looks like this:

```
| contactlogs | CREATE TABLE `contactlogs` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`contact_email` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`company_name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`telephone` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`fax` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`subject` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`message` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

When I retrieve the data that was saved, the message field is often cut off, with a garbage character at the end (I assume because it might not have saved all the data of the last character.

The website itself is in cakephp.  The data is being saved by just doing a $this->model->save($data) (Haven't changed anything about the way it's saving, the model itself is empty).  There's no special database settings.  Just set host, login, persistent => false, driver => mysql, database, prefix.

Comment: `CHARACTER SET latin1`... since when was Japanese part of `latin1`?

Comment: Those lines that are latin1 are not meant to be storing Japanese characters.  Only those fields that have collate utf8_unicode_ci are.  Yeah, I know it probably seems like they all should be utf8, but it's for a pre-existing website, and I'd like to avoid changing the database setup if at all possible.  (Though I'm not at all convinced that it will be possible to fix this bug without doing so.)

Comment: You probably need to set the encoding for the database connection to utf8 in the [configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html). The default is usually latin1.

Comment: I tried adding 'encoding' => 'utf8' to the DATABASE_CONFIG table, but then the characters retrieved look like "ã‚ã„ã†ãˆãŠã€‚ã‚ã„ã†ãˆãŠã€‚ã‚ã„"  I should probably note though that this is also with an older version of cakephp.  1.3, I believe.

Comment: @Kai It is possible that your mysql version was old and didn't support all kinds of unicode. from V5.5 more is supported. like unicode emojis. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Your DB and tables are probably under latin1 *default collation*, so without `'encoding' => 'utf8'` in your database config cake is gonna be talking to the DB in latin1. The transcoding of UTF to latin1 and back leaves space for data to be lost. This is not really cake's problem.

So go on and change the connection to UTF and all default collations in the DB too. Newly saved data will be displayed fine, for old ones it will depend, I won't go into details cause it's out of context.